# Reorder Rows to Match Another Dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that includes latitude, longitude, and species name as variables with 16 observations.

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   species_name [16]
      lat    lon species_name            
    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                   
 1  48.8  -124.  Balanophyllia elegans   
 2  59.0    11.0 Caryophyllia smithii    
 3   1.54  125.  Coscinaraea wellsi      
 4  47.8   -59.8 Flabellum alabastrum    
 5 -17.5  -150.  Phymastrea curta        
 6   6.06  100.  Physogyra lichtensteini 
 7   5.77  103.  Plerogyra sinuosa       
 8 -17.6  -150.  Pocillopora woodjonesi  
 9   4.77   73.1 Psammocora contigua     
10   3.8    72.8 Psammocora digitata     
11   1.93 -158.  Psammocora explanulata  
12   4.77   73.1 Psammocora nierstraszi  
13  14.0    48.2 Pseudosiderastrea tayami
14  22.2    39.0 Stylophora pistillata   
15 -17.5  -150.  Tubastraea sp. BMOO04410
16 -17.6  -150.  Verrillofungia concinna
```

I want to reorder the species_name such that it follows another dataframes order for species_name.

```
    GeoTree.Scler$tip.label
1    Pocillopora_woodjonesi
2     Stylophora_pistillata
3      Caryophyllia_smithii
4     Balanophyllia_elegans
5  Tubastraea_sp._BMOO04410
6      Flabellum_alabastrum
7   Physogyra_lichtensteini
8         Plerogyra_sinuosa
9          Phymastrea_curta
10       Coscinaraea_wellsi
11   Psammocora_explanulata
12  Verrillofungia_concinna
13      Psammocora_contigua
14      Psammocora_digitata
15 Pseudosiderastrea_tayami
16   Psammocora_nierstraszi
```

I've tried to search how to do this but I can't seem to find any answers. An example of the desired output is:

```
 # A tibble: 16 x 3
    # Groups:   species_name [16]
          lat    lon species_name  
     1 -17.6  -150.  Pocillopora woodjonesi
     2  22.2    39.0 Stylophora pistillata
```

Where the first dataframe is reordered in the order of the second.

Answer (score 0):

So if you make an ordered factor and sort by the factor:

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 <- tibble(lat = c(22.2, -17.6),
           lon = c(39.0, -150),
           species_name = c("Stylophora pistillata", "Pocillopora woodjonesi"))



df_2 <- tibble(tip.label = c("Pocillopora_woodjonesi", "Stylophora_pistillata"))

df_1 <- df_1 %>%
  mutate(species_name = gsub(" ", "_", species_name ))

levels <-  df_2$tip.label

df_1 <- df_1 %>%
    mutate(df_1, species_name = factor(species_name, levels = levels))%>%
    arrange(species_name)

    # A tibble: 2 x 3
     lat   lon species_name          
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                 
1 -17.6  -150 Pocillopora woodjonesi
2  22.2    39 Stylophora pistillata
```